# Manage dependency depending on the container - JSON-P

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I have a project that uses JSON-P and it's built into a webapp that works with various containers like Tomcat, Wildfly, WebLogic.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to add that JSON-P glassfish implementation only if I use Tomcat, and leave it out if I use other application servers like JBosss or Wildfly or WebLogic because as we know the application containers already provide the implementation for that thing.

What do you think about it? What do you usually do?

Comment: You could manage it using maven profile, with a specific tomcat profile that include the dependency you need.